# How to use the result from a procedure in another procedure in SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, procedure

I'm trying to combine a result mixed with some `SELECT`s.
I wanted to set `@result` combined with the result of `[proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum]` procedure but It didn't work.

```sql
declare @str varchar(300)
declare @result varchar(200)
declare @temp varchar(20)
declare @i int
set @str='110,120,130,140'
set @result=''
set @temp=''
set @i=0
while @i<len(@str)/4+1
begin
    set @temp=substring(@str,1,3)
    set @str=substring(@str,2,len(@str))
    set @result=@result+  exec [proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum] @temp 
    set @i=@i+1
end
select @temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd make use of output variables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum
    @temp varchar(20),
    @outValue varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    --do stuff

    --before you leave the method or do your final SELECT
    SET @outValue = 'whatever your result is'

    --more stuff
END
```

Then in your code, you just go:

```
DECLARE @outValue VARCHAR(20)

-- rest of your code

EXEC [proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum] @temp, @outValue OUT
SET @result = @result + @outValue
```

Alternatively, you could just dump the results of the SP into a temp table, then read from it into your @Result variable.

Comment: Thank you so much,next time I'll bring you to my School's Cafe ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can't interpolate the result of one procedure by appending it.
I am assuming now that `[proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum]` returns a scalar result.

So run `exec [proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum] @temp` in another line of batch (before set @result = @result + call)

Your query should look like,

> > declare @scalarResult = exec [proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum] @temp 
> >     set @result=@result+ @scalarResult

Comment: The value of `exec` is the return code (of type int) from the procedure. This will only work if `proc_Get_Frame_CourseNum` is returning its result using a `return` statement (and it's an int). If it's currently returning e.g. a single row/column value containing the scalar value, this method will not work.